# I keep getting this error in rubyTest.rb:11:in `+': String can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError) from Test.rb:11:in `<main>'

Tags: ruby

Im trying to do a project for school and i can't figure out how to fix this error. The equations I'm using look correct. I can't find the mistake. Are the equations right?

```
puts "Hello welcome to the bank of homeless people! How may I help you?" 
puts "--type 'deposit' to deposit money to your checkings account"
puts "--type 'withdraw' to withdraw money from your checking account"
puts "--type 'display' to display your currant balance"

descion = gets.chomp.downcase
balance=0

case descion
when 'deposit'
    puts "how much do you want to deposit?"

    deposit = gets.chomp
    balance = balance + deposit

    puts "#{deposit} has been added to your checking account"
when 'withdraw'
    puts "how much do you want to remove?"

    withdraw = gets.chomp
    balance = balance - withdraw

    puts "#{withdraw} has been removed from your checking account"  
when 'display'
    puts "you have #{balance} in your account"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`gets` returns a `string` so your equations are trying to add a `fixnum` with a `string`.

Try using `to_i` on `deposit` and `withdraw`

Answer (score 0):

A string is not a digit, therefore Ruby is attempting to find a digit but can't find it within your string.

What you need to do is convert the strings into digits..

For example:

`x = "1_000"`; `#<= "1000" normal string`

`y = "1_000".to_i`; `#<= 1000 string converted to integer`

You can also go one step further and call `.to_f` which will turn it into a floating point number, or a decimal.

`z = "1_000.to_f`; `#<= 1000.0 string converted to floating point num`

I'd suggest you go and look around on the web for some information on strings and how to use them, along with what you can do with them. Here's a good start: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html